# Type mismatch on variable and argument (Int / Int)

Tags: graphql, syntax-error, type-mismatch

Given the following GraphQL request and variables:

**Request:**

```
query accounts($filter:AccountFilter, $first_:String, $skip_:Int) {
  accounts(filter: $filter, first: $first_, skip: $skip_) {
    id
  }
}
```

**Variables:**

```json
{
  "filter": {},
  "first_": "3",
  "skip_": 0
}
```

**Note:** I added underscores to the `first_` and `skip_` variable names to help distinguish them from the arguments `first` and `skip`.

I'm getting the following errors:

`"Type mismatch on variable $first_ and argument first (String / Int)"`

`"Type mismatch on variable $skip_ and argument skip (Int / Int)"`

The first error I created on purpose as a sanity check. The value in the variables should be `"first": 3,` and not `"first": "3",`. The second error I don't understand why I'm getting it. How is `Int` and `Int` Type mismatched? The `first` variable/argument error reoprts the same error `(Int / Int)` when I correctly pass `3` and change `String` to `Int`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Backend Specs:**
Ruby on Rails

**Argument Specs:**

```
"""
Interface for the Account model
"""
type Account {
  friendlyId: String!
  id: ID!
  locations: [Location!]!
  name: String!
  participants: [User!]!
  primaryLocation: Location!
  primarySiteContact: User!
  siteContacts: [User!]!
}

input AccountFilter {
  OR: [AccountFilter!]
}

type Query {
  """
  Details for an Account
  """
  accountDetails(id: ID): Account

  """
  A list of Accounts
  """
  accounts(filter: AccountFilter, first: Int, skip: Int): [Account!]
}
```

Comment: where? what env/lang? ... BE specs/arg types for this query?

Comment: Can you share your schema?

Comment: @xadm Sorry, I didn't back end would present differences, and I thought I had inferred that `first` and `skip` are supposed to be `Int`s.

Comment: @JosephHall, I added the relevant schema parts (see second edit). This is propritary so I only included what I felt was necessary to know. If you need something else, let me know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it can be language/implementation (parser) specific problem as gql types/args looks OK

Comment: @xadm Thanks. I'll have to do some more research for this. Possibly submit an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is(was) a known issue with graphql for Ruby. The issue seems to have a PR and fix avaiable but I'm still having this issue even after updating my `graphql` gem.

You can view the issue here:
https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/2784

The fix that works for me included in that post is here:

```rb
def self.type_from_ast(*args)
  type = super
  type == GraphQL::Types::Int ? type.to_graphql : type
end
```

Comment: I have since needed to remove this fix as the library has been updated now and no longer has this problem.